# Real Time DIV background color update based on database value

Tags: php, jquery

I want the div to change color based on the value that is retrieved from the database.
The current code doesn't give any color and uses the set css color.

**Main div css**

```
.status{    background: #000;   }
```

**status.php**

```
if ($user_data['status'] === "1") { echo "online"; } 
else {                              echo "offline";  }
```

**The ajax function**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'status.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data === "online") {
               $('.status').css('background', '#40A547');
            } else { 
               $('.status').css('background', '#7f8c8d');
            }
        }
    });
   }, 2000);
});
```

**The main div**

```
 <div class="status">something</div>
```

Please help me out. All help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check by putting alert in the success whether it is even coming in the success or not!

Comment: try `$('.status').css({background: '#7f8c8d'});`

Comment: $('#divid').css('background','#40A547');
if this not work the press f12 and see whether there is an error on console if yes hten first resolve this.

Comment: Can you post the response that you are getting from "status.php"?

Comment: @sandip i placed an alert in both if and else and i am only getting the else to alert.

Comment: @sravis if the user is logged in, their status would become 1 in the database and it should echo "online", otherwise it should echo "offline" that should go into the ajax function into the if statement

Comment: if you are always getting response and its always getting "offline" then there must be problem in `if ($user_data['status'] === "1")`. Check and see what response do you have for `$user_data['status']`.

Comment: On a side note: sending a server request every 2 seconds is not the best practice. Avoid it unless you really have to do it. Imagine the number of just **status** requests your server will get every 2 seconds if you have thousands of users!

Comment: I tried alert('<?php echo $user_data['status'];?>'); but it gives me an error "unexpected token <". And it's 2 seconds just for testing

Comment: I would suggest using `console.log` not `alert`... much less obnoxious for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be identified use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'status.php',
        datatype:"application/json",
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            if (data === "online") {
                $('.status').css('background', '#40A547');
            } else {
                $('.status').css('background', '#7f8c8d');
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            //if pointer is comming it means there is some error in the back end code
        }
    });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Now check your in the `firebug` it will show you the `error details`, if you don't have firebug add it and then check.

also put some `content in the div` so that it will be visible. If there are no content div doesn't appear.

Hope this will help!

Comment: @GoGo so did you tried by putting the alert in the success as well as in the error of ajax?

Comment: i placed error: function(){alert("error");} but didn't see anything in firebug, also i did place an alert in both the if and else and only the else was alerting

Comment: @GoGo so you are saying that it is coming in the success and in that in the else part right? if i am right everything is working just put some content like <div class="status">to the the background color</div> and it will work!

Comment: yes you are correct. I do have content in there. I just removed it from my main question for cleaner look but it's like this in the actual code: <div class="status">' .$price . '</div> but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @GoGo it will not work as it should be like : <div class="status"><?php echo $price; ?></div>

Comment: } else { 
           alert(data)
           $('.status').css('background', '#7f8c8d');
        }

Comment: @MatTaylor it gives me all the div in the alerted message

Comment: @GoGo well can please put some hard code value to test in the div? like <div class="status">to the the background color</div> if this works it means there is problem in the concatenation!

Comment: i have a value there i wrote "something" in the div. Now I am trying to detect that problem yeah

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything in your div, so it's basically 0 height and width so you don't see anything (which is what I assume you mean by "current code doesn't give any color").

If you specify a height and width, or add something inside your div (even a `&nbsp;`, you should see the background color.

Comment: i emptied it for a cleaner question here, i have a bunch of things in it in my actual code

Answer (score 0):

That means you are not getting 'online' back from your ajax. you need to edit your PHP code that you are AJAXing to purely say 'online', no divs or markup.

Comment: what do you mean by no divs? could you show me an example of the code you mean

Comment: If from alert(data) you are getting an alert with divs inside it, then the callback from your php page is wrong.  Whatever appears in the alert(data) is purely what your php script is echoing out.

Comment: i fixed it. i had an error actually showing up inside the alert. now when i alert(data); i get "offline"

Comment: when i logged in, looks like my error:function(){alert("error");} is called

Comment: always do alert(data). This will show you what is coming back.

Comment: yeah i never see "online" so it ignores it for some reason, always "offline" is alerted

Comment: @GoGo why it is going in the else is your question or why it is not showing background color?

Comment: So you need to sort your PHP script

Comment: @MatTaylor I am not sure what is wrong with it though.. It looks fine to me, i tried changing it to a true/false instead of online/offline, but it didn't help. @ sandip, it is showing the background color indicated in the else statement, and when i log in, it still shows the color from the else statement rather than the if statement

Comment: without your full PHP script we cannot help?

Comment: I gave you all the php script.. there is nothing else. $user_data['status'] is just a retrieved value from the database that i use in my main code of the whole website, and I know for a fact that it works as I have it working for other pages

Comment: $user_data['status'] is not set in the PHP script then.  Thats why it never equals '1'

Comment: @GoGo this simply means that you $user_data['status'] don't  have value as 1, from where the values are getting in $user_data

Comment: yeah that was the issue, i had to put reference to what user_data was before I could use it!